# How to traverse skos:broader property to list tourist places in various cities

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Any help in my learning will be highly appreciated.

**Problem statement:**

Need to print list of tourist places in various cities

I have http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Tourism_by_city category which i have to explore. The problem is this category is a skos:broader of various other categories like `http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Tourism_in_Bratislava` which in itself is a `skos:broader` of `http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Visitor_attractions_in_Bratislava` which contains `dcterms:subject` property and which is the list of tourist places.
I have to explore all cities starting from Tourism_by_city category.

**What I have done**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?places 
WHERE { 
?entity skos:broader* <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Tourism_by_city> .
?places dcterms:subject ?entity
}
```

**Problem:**

`skos:broader` is further exploring the graph, i want to restrict it till `Visitor_attractions` level. Also `skos:broader` is exploring all the categories but i want it to explore for just `Visitor_attractions` category.

Level 1 : Tourism_by_city - > explore all `skos:broader of`

Level 2 : Tourism_by_xxxcity -> explore only `category:Vistors_attractions_by_xxxcity`

Level 3 : Do not explore further.

Is this achievable ?

Please do let me know if question is unclear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the question, I don't know whether this is the only viable option:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (str(?city) as ?City) (str(?label) as ?Attractions)
WHERE { 
?entity skos:broader <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Tourism_by_city> .
?places skos:broader ?entity .
?places rdfs:label ?city .
FILTER langMatches(lang(?city),"en") .
?attractions dcterms:subject ?places .
?attractions rdfs:label ?label .
FILTER langMatches(lang(?label),"en").
FILTER (if (isliteral(?city ),  contains(str(?city ), "Visitor"), false))
} 
ORDER BY ASC(?city)
```

Comment: ,i am also running with same issue , can you give me some step to do this. i want to list out all the respective attractions from 'dbpedia' or 'wikipedia'?

Comment: Could you please elaborate it further? Or post a question itself. Thanks